# How to make question sentence form?

Tags: american-english

I want to know about the making question sentence form.

Are these sentences correct? 
What post-it do you have? 
What post-it are you having?

As I know, above sentences are the same. But are there any difference them?

Comment: Hi snail, As I know, above sentences are the same. But are there any difference them?

Comment: What are you trying to express with these sentences?

Comment: Ok. I want to know about the difference between 'I always do' and 'I'm always doing something'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the verb "have" is used as a stative verb  to mean own, possess or hold, we usually don't use it in the continuous form. So the correct sentence is "What post-it do you have?"